# Load XML Local Infile if no rows contain the same value in Java

Tags: java, mysql, xml

I am going to load some XML file into the database.

But I also want to check if the same XML file has been loaded into the database before.

I don't want to load the same XML file twice because it will cause duplicates.

Is there some syntax like "LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE WHERE ... ?"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to load some xml file and insert to database, but you don't want to insert the duplicated xml?

you can calculate out the xml file's md5, and save in a HashSet
before your insert you can use set.contains(obj) to check out if you insert before.